# My python code for fetching the IP address of a given website takes more than 3 minutes to fetch the result.Any probable reason?

Tags: python, ip

```
import os
def get_ip_address(url):
    command ="tracert "+url
    process = os.popen(command)
    result=str(process.read())
    start=result.find('[')
    end=result.find(']')
    ip_addr=result[start+1:end]
    return ip_addr
print get_ip_address('google.com')
```

The code just runs the tracert google.com command in cmd and retrieves the result by adjusting the string result according to my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tracert` will hang if one of the servers on the way is down or just takes a long time to reply. Try to use `nslookup`, or use a dedicated library (like [this one](http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html) for example) instead of directly relying on OS commands.